# Merge 2 dataframes on closest past date

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, date, merge

I have 2 dataframes with column 0 for 'Date'.

There are more Secondary dates than Main dates and they are different (although close in time).

I would like to merge both dataframes keeping Main dates as a reference and choosing Secondary dates (rows) to be merged based on being the immediate date before the Main date.

```
main = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.to_datetime(
      ['2013-07-23', '2013-10-28', '2014-01-27', '2014-04-23',
       '2014-07-22', '2014-10-20', '2015-01-27', '2015-04-27',
       '2015-07-21', '2015-10-27', '2016-01-26', '2016-04-26', '2016-07-26'] ) })

         Date
0  2013-07-23
1  2013-10-28
2  2014-01-27
3  2014-04-23
4  2014-07-22
5  2014-10-20
6  2015-01-27
7  2015-04-27
8  2015-07-21
9  2015-10-27
10 2016-01-26
11 2016-04-26
12 2016-07-26
```

And

```
sec = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2013-07-01',periods=42,freq='1MS')})

         Date
0  2013-07-01
1  2013-08-01
2  2013-09-01
3  2013-10-01
...

38 2016-09-01
39 2016-10-01
40 2016-11-01
41 2016-12-01
```

Dates should be merged with this logic although keeping only Date Main and the rest of the columns for both dataframes:

(sorted reverse chronologically)

```
MERGED
      Date Main    Date Secondary
0     2016-07-26   2016-07-01
1     2016-04-26   2016-04-01
2     2016-01-26   2016-01-01
3     2015-10-27   2015-10-01
4     2015-07-21   2015-07-01
5     2015-04-27   2015-04-01
6     2015-01-27   2015-01-01
7     2014-10-20   2014-10-01
8     2014-07-22   2014-07-01
9     2014-04-23   2014-04-01
10    2014-01-27   2014-01-01
11    2013-10-28   2013-10-01
12    2013-07-23   2013-07-01
```

The solutions I found are related to merging 2 dates that are the closest, but for this case the closest could mean a Secondary date after the Main date which violates the 'past' condition.

> [Merge dataframe on closest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149536/merge-dataframe-on-closest-date)

This one looks similar, though I do not know how to apply it to my case.

> [How to merge two dataframes based on the closest (or most recent) timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332914/how-to-merge-two-dataframes-based-on-the-closest-or-most-recent-timestamp)

Comment: `pd.merge_asof()`

Comment: Thanks @djk47463 ! I see that there is a parameter tolerance=pd.Timedelta(), but if I understand it correctly it finds the nearest value (could be future). How do set it towards the past?

Comment: It works on past closest only, look at the `allow_exact_matches` parameter

Comment: @djk47463 since pandas 0.20 you can set direction to backward (default), forward, or nearest.  Doesn't matter for this question of course since OP wants backward anyway, just fyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a try with `merge_asof`:

```
df = pd.merge_asof( main.set_index('Date').sort_index(),
                    sec.set_index('Date',drop=False).sort_index(),
                    left_index=True, 
                    right_index=True,
                    direction='backward')  # backward is the default, so you
                                           # can leave this out if you prefer

df.rename(columns={'Date':'Date_sec'})\
  .sort_index(ascending=False).reset_index()
```

A syntax note:  The `drop=False` is necessary to ensure that the date from the secondary dataframe is preserved.  Without it, the merged dataframe will only contain the date from the main dataframe.

Results:

```
         Date   Date_sec
0  2016-07-26 2016-07-01
1  2016-04-26 2016-04-01
2  2016-01-26 2016-01-01
3  2015-10-27 2015-10-01
4  2015-07-21 2015-07-01
5  2015-04-27 2015-04-01
6  2015-01-27 2015-01-01
7  2014-10-20 2014-10-01
8  2014-07-22 2014-07-01
9  2014-04-23 2014-04-01
10 2014-01-27 2014-01-01
11 2013-10-28 2013-10-01
12 2013-07-23 2013-07-01
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for some reason I am getting TypeError: merge_asof() got an unexpected keyword argument 'direction'

Comment: @Diego  you probably have an older version of pandas.  I believe `direction` was added in 0.20.0 but `backward` is the default so you can probably just leave it off.  I only added it here for clarity since it's sometimes better to be explicit with keyword arguments even when unnecessary.

Comment: You are right! Pandas upgraded. Now I am getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable on right_index=True. Researched but could not find any clues...

Comment: @Diego  I'm not sure, but it may be a data issue.  I edited your question to include code for creating the two dataframes.  See if that works for you and if it does then:  (1) check that your real data has datetime dtype for 'Date", (2) check for missing values NaN or NaT (not a time).  Your message seems to indicate a missing value somewhere, as best I can guess without having your data

Comment: Thank you for the edition! I performed dropna and pd.notnull checks , even np.inf and still get the same Error. I will keep on checking...

Comment: @Diego  I dunno then.  Maybe also check to see if you have non-unique dates in one or the other dataframe?  (altho I'm not sure if that would or should be a problem)  `merge_asof` is pretty new, and awesome compared to not having it, but I'm sure it still has some bugs on account of the newness, so it's possible you are hitting one.

Comment: Appreciate time and effort. Thanks a lot!